# Desktop graphics card on laptop

Tags: pci-express, mac-mini

Does anyone know of a external adaptor or enclosure, that would allow a nvidia graphics card (PCI E) to connect to a Mac mini, over USB3 or better yet thundbolt port as it suposedly has more bandwidth.

Maybe it's a crazy idea but iv been looking around for a while and not really finding what I'm thinking of

Thanks

Comment: It does not exist.

Comment: That's what I was starting to think, but thought it was still worth asking. Too bad

Answer (score 1):

A qualified yes.  It has been done, at least with what appears to be a MacBook Pro:

http://www.anandtech.com/show/7987/running-an-nvidia-gtx-780-ti-over-thunderbolt-2

Near the bottom of the page, it describes a cheaper method:

> What you need is a Thunderbolt to ExpressCard adapter (like Sonnet's Echo ExpressCard Pro) and an ExpressCard to PCIe adapter (like the BPlus PE4L V2.1), which together come in at $240 when bought straight from the manufacturers' online stores. Add a cheap ~400W power supply to that and the  total is less than $300 (without the GPU, of course). If you are interested in external Thunderbolt GPUs, I recommend that you take a good look at Tech Inferno forums as they have several guides and other resources from troubleshooting to benchmarks.

Whether or not this is practical or easy is a different matter.